# php (or better choice?) for sending turn data to a simple webapp game

Tags: php, web-applications, backend, data-exchange

I have a simple 2d strategy combat game that I wrote in javascript and jQuery.   The user controls 3 or 4 characters as they fight monsters (small screen cap here https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkkXm.jpg).

It is not realtime, it is turn based (player's turn, computers turn) and the game is designed for a phone user, mainly office workers on their morning commute. iPhone user is the main target. Game development is in early stages but currently playable. This is a web app played in browser.

My biggest issue is that if you switch applications (such as answering a phone call) and then switch back the page reloads (therefore the web app reloads) and you lose any progress you have made.

I have tested this as a web app download (using mobile safari Add To Home Screen) but the reload problem persists when switching.

I'm resisting wrapping this and delivering through the Apple app store ... instead I want to create a backend that will save the player's turns.  Simple tasks such as

- javascript function in my web app would send turn data in the form of
  a string
- when the web page (and web app) reload, it retrieves the last
  recorded turn
- player would need a login

I'm interested in PHP as I've had some experience with it from deconstructing and altering wordpress themes. The only other languages I know are front end (html, css, javascript, jQuery).

Can PHP cover the above tasks in a secure manner or should I be looking at learning an alternate language?

Any guidance is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. PHP can do what you want, as can really any other server-side language.  You would just use ajax calls to send data updates to the backend server.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but are there any security risks with choosing PHP for this over something like Java?  (sorry I can't upvote your answer as I don't have 15 reputation points)

Comment: Outside of individual vulnerabilities of the specific languages and the web server platform of choice, pretty much any language would allow to utilize the same sort of encryption mechanisms and security practices.  As with anything, the developer should have an understanding of how to best set up a secure app environment as well as design a secure app (i.e. prevent against SQL Injection, XSS, CSRF, etc.)